# On MacBook, how do i put my phone number for iMessages instead of my apple ID/email

Tags: macos, icloud, messages

I would go on iMessages and message my friends and it will message them on my gmail rather than the number i use on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

Open Messages Preferences (click Messages menu at the top-left of your screen and click Preferences) and choose the iMessage tab.

At the bottom of this screen will be a popup where you can choose what to compose new messages from.

If you don't see a phone number here, make sure you're signed in on your iPhone. Go to Settings > Messages and check if you're signed in or not.

Comment: This is excellent - one point to remember - if your contacts already know your AppleID email or you’ve messaged them, there’s no way to reverse that. They have to forget your contact, but this will change the “caller ID” for all new conversations going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is no difference between your email address or phone number in iMessages. They are simply identifiers for you on iMessage.

iMessages uses neither the actual email nor the phone number, but instead does a lookup in a database to find your device's unique ID. So, its not using your Gmail nor your phone number to contact you, its using iMessage.

If you have noticed, when you start a new message, and type in someone's name, it shows their name in Blue, thus indicating an iMessage link/registration.

You can choose which contact form is used to identify you to iMessages, via the iMessages configuration in System Preferences. Here you can choose, for example, to disable you phone number as a reference to your account.